# ASP.NET httphandlers webconfig file Integrated mode

Tags: asp.net, web-config, httphandler, integrated-pipeline-mode

```
  I have a web.config file which contains 

    <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.pdf" type="InfomationDev.Info.write.writeModule, InformationDev.Info.write"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    </system.Web>
     **After running appcmd migrate command IIS6 to IIS7 we got new section**  



    <system.webServer>
```

```
 <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
            <remove name="ScriptResource" />
            <add name="*.pdf" verb="*" path="*.pdf" type="InfomationDev.Info.write.writeModule, InformationDev.Info.write"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
                 type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
                 type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

- **The problem is:**
          if I removed completely `hhtpHandlers` section it is working in Integrated mode.
          if I removed completely `system.webserver` section it is working in Classic mode.
          If I wanted to work on both modes(sometimes classic & Integrated) so I added both sections as shown above throwing `exception 500 Internal server error`.I want to work
          in both Integrated & classic modes without using 
          `validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"`.
  How can we do that?